# Why not cast inside overridden .clone?

Tags: java, clone

I understand how Java cloning works and the arguments against using it. Lets say I am dead set on using it anyway.

For the sake of convenience I would like to write a clone method for class Foo as follows:

```
@Override
public Foo clone(){
    Foo f = (Foo)super.clone();
    //Replace mutable fields
    return f;
}
```

As far as I can tell this would be safe. However, I noticed that Cloneable classes in the API do not do this. Is there a reason for this and is it bad style?

Comment: Note that this is only useful if you use it like this: `Foo foo = ...; Foo bar = foo.clone()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Back before Java 5, covariant return types weren't allowed at all, so `Foo clone()` wouldn't even compile.
Since a lot of `Cloneable` classes have been written a long time ago, that's probably the reason for majority of the cases.

I suspect that newer classes don't use it simply because `clone()` is known to be quite a handful, and when people rarely do use it, they don't even think that they could cast it. They find some "how to implement clone()" question and write the code in the old fashioned way.

Comment: Good old "it's so broke no one ever even tried to waste time trying to fix it".

Answer (score 3):

`Object.clone()` creates a new object where all fields have the same value as the original. For fields of reference type, this means that the new field is simply a reference to the same object as the original. It does not `clone` fields. Therefore in many cases, the default implementation would lead to shared data, which may be undesirable. For example, if `ArrayList.clone()` used the default implementation, you would end up with two `ArrayList` instances sharing the same backing array.

If all the fields of an object are immutable, it may be a good idea to simply cast the result of `super.clone()` to the appropriate type.

Comment: The API is quite vague about what `clone()` is expected to be doing but it does say: `Typically, this means copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep structure" of the object being cloned and replacing the references to these objects with references to the copies.`, so a `clone()` should ideally return a deep copy. Ideally but not necessarily...

Comment: If the fields are all immutable, there is no difference between a deep and a shallow copy.

Comment: That is true but how is that related to the question? I'm a bit lost. :)

Comment: It answers the question. The reason for not simply doing `(MyClass) super.clone()` is that this is a shallow copy, whereas a deep copy is usually required. I've said it's ok to do it in the case where there is no difference between deep/shallow copy.

Comment: Oh, I see. Fair enough, I thought the question was purely about why we don't use a covariant return type when overriding `clone()` and not about casting `super.clone()`.

Comment: You may be right. Rereading the question I'm not really sure.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, but I was only wonder about covariant return types. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, this is definitely not a bad style in fact its preferable that you do this since the release of java 1.5, because covariant return types were
introduced in release 1.5 as part of generics, and by doing so, you are making your API easier to use (no casting would be required).

source (Effective java 2nd edition).